# are Slow Queries Damaging?

Tags: mysql, performance

I know that slow queries can annoy client or otherwise take a long time to finish.
Is there a reason besides making them faster that you should optimize a query?
In other words, does a query running on a server for long periods of time do any damage or otherwise cause issues to the server?

Comment: Not by itself but it depends on the actual query, if it was written badly or maliciously, then possibly.

Comment: I suppose if you run a query that pegs the server's CPU for hours on end, you might slightly speed up the normal wear and tear process..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slow queries, evenif its read can create a lot of problems. As mentioned by symcbean, the resource(I/O, memory etc) usage will be high on the server. 
I mostly handle with InnoDB tables. Last week, due to some config issue, all the report queries started hitting master DB instead of slave. Some of the issues we faced were

1. The I/O was very high
2. Number of connections on the server was as high as 700+ (normally its held below 200, lucky enough we were still able to connect to MySQL!!)
3. Even INSERT INTO .. VALUES() was slow, the most frequently table had 100+ INSERT queries waiting and many of them time out soon. (This never happens on normal days)
4. Other queries simple SELECT on ids was also slow.

Also to note, if you are doing a WRITE operation, be it MyISAM(table level)/InnoDB(row level) lock will be issued. That can  your life even worse.

Yeah, it was worst case, but slow queries can bring down you whole system.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a really long-running query on a system with a lot of write activity, maintaining the [MVCC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiversion_concurrency_control) integrity can get progressively more expensive. Since a query on InnoDB takes place on a consistent snapshot of the data, subsequent writes are queued up in a fashion until the query closes out.

It's usually best to create a replica database for reporting purposes if you're doing this frequently. MySQL's master/slave system makes this fairly straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

With MyISAM tables (and in some cases with other engines) it will block other queries from starting - so they will take a long time to complete. There can be timeouts elsewhere (e.g. on webserver, and user's patience) which may result in the connection being terminated - in the absence of transactions this can cause data integrity issues.

Even in the absence of blocking, long queries consume resources meaning that other things happening on the server at the same time will slow down.

On a badly configured server, it can cause too much memory to be consumed - first going into swap and slowing down massively, and potentially triggering the OOM killer.